# MODX Revo установить Yandex карту

Tags: yandex-maps-api, modx, revo

Хочу добавить на сайт яндекс карту. На настоящий момент задача - просто отобразить карту на пустой странице. Не получается установить [компонент](https://modx.pro/components/5033#), запнулся на 3-ем пункте. Что надо сделать-то? Там спросил, но все вымерли, похоже.

Comment: Когда добавляете новое TV поле, там есть вкладка "Доступно для шаблонов" - вот там надо поставить галочку на вашем шаблоне.

Comment: спасибо, разобрался